# Core of printf() function in C

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, printf, lib

Is there a way to get to the core of printf? I need an USB output as fast as possible, but `printf()` is very slow, so I want to get rid of all the formatting that is happening inside the function. Where is printf declared? It is most likely in the stdout library, but where can I find it (I´m using visual studio code).

Background (Working on Raspberry Pi Pico with SDK lib - but not relevant for this question):

I want to read 16Bit Hex values from SPI1 and write them within an interrupt to USB in "realtime". So my program kinda looks like this:

```
Do nothing until SPI Interrupt triggers
Read data from SPI1
Write data to COM19 on PC via USB
```

The SPI data from the master is coming in at a rate of 4MHz and there is a gap of about 480ns between data words. One data packet is taking about 4,5us (measured from bit1 of word1 to bit1 of word2). Means the maximum time of the interrupt should not be greater than 4,5us. The interrupt function with `printf()` takes about 9us to process, so thats too slow and some data is not getting caught. `Write()` is able to process within the time of one cycle and only takes about 2us. The problem with it is, that the data is printed as ASCII on the COM Port (Putty). I disabled a lot of the SDK functions to optimize the runtime and I was wondering can I do the same with `printf()` ? Must be possible to write directly into the TX register and send it to the PC, but I wasn´t able to find anything about this topic on my research.

Either I need to speed up the `printf()` function, or find some alternative, because it is clearly slowing down my program.

Comment: Why not use [`puts`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) if you don't need any formatting?

Comment: The Pico SDK provides `uart_putc()` and `uart_puts()` that would be much faster than the parsing done by `printf()`.

Comment: If you want speed, don't bloat your data by transforming them into ASCII. Send them as binary, make them human-readable later and offline. You are not able to read 222'222 numbers per second, watching the output in PuTTY. Is your PC even capable of scrolling fast enough?

Comment: @the busybee the data need to be read by another tool later. I need to check if the data is recieved correctly at the com port (sending constant hex numbers now so i can screenshot and validate the putty output). I guess it doesnt matter how i  stress the com port, either by putty or by another software that reads the data?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin is the uart_puts going to USB or the UART output on the pico? i´d expect the data to be sent to the uart tx pins  (e.g. pin 1) when using the uart outputs

Comment: I would write a receiving program that does the checks and write into a file. Currently you are receiving at least 5 bytes for the 4 characters and a newline, in binary it would be only 2 bytes for the 16 bit value.

Comment: How long is one recording, how many values do you have in one go? You could detach the transfer from the acquirement, the Pico has a lot of memory.

Comment: @thebusybee binary would work as well. It´s always 10*16 Bits that are coming in at 4Mhz. There´s a 18us break between each 10*16 Bit datablock. These are fixed values, that I can´t change. How can I detatch the acquirement from the transfer? The problem is that i have to work with spi interrupts because i can´t use the CS pin. So within the interrupt i need to read and push the data out in one go, before the next interrupt is firing. About the file writing: I just tried with fwrite(). Timing wise it doesn´t look too bad, but do you know where the file is usually created?

Comment: I looked at this example:    FILE *fp;
   char str[] = "Hello File";
   fp = fopen( "file.txt" , "w" );
   fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str) , fp );
   fclose(fp);

Comment: @0i9n - you can configure to go to either. The USB can either be in *Host* or *Device* mode depending how it's configured. Pico comes with a tinyUSB implementation as part of the SDK. If you are using a 2nd Pico as the debug probe, then you can write directly to the PC (PuTTY) using the uart from the SWI serial debug wire.

Answer (score 2):

How's this for speed..

```
char *hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
char buf[4];
buf[3] = hex[n >> 0 & 0xF];
buf[2] = hex[n >> 4 & 0xF];
buf[1] = hex[n >> 8 & 0xF];
buf[0] = hex[n >>12 & 0xF];
write( fd, buf, sizeof buf );
```

There's 'endianess' to consider, but can't imagine you can get faster than this...

EDIT: Then again, there's the branchless version without any table. Something like this:

```
buf[3] = n    &0xF, buf[3] += '0' + (buf[3] > 9) * 7;
buf[2] = n>> 4&0xF, buf[2] += '0' + (buf[2] > 9) * 7;
buf[1] = n>> 8&0xF, buf[1] += '0' + (buf[1] > 9) * 7;
buf[0] = n>>12    , buf[0] += '0' + (buf[0] > 9) * 7;
```

Those "2nd half" tweaks to the values look like they'd be amenable to a parallel operation in systems that might support that.

Comment: There is absolutely no endiannes whatsoever to consider, but you do need to reverse the order of the indices (always, not just for one specific endianness). That is, `buf[3] = hex[n >> 0 & 0xF];` etc.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I don't know the data source, nor do I know what the 16bits represent. How the data source may or may not sequence the bytes is "endianess"... I've flipped the sequence (edit) because you seem to know these things and I appreciate your input...

Comment: You can get faster if you use two tables of 256 characters each and use the bytes as index without any shifting. Or even use one or more tables of 65536 entries. The Pico has a lot of memory, and as often, it's a trade of memory for speed.

Comment: You need to consider endianness when you *reinterpret* a number as a sequence of bytes, i.e. `char* c = (char*)&number;`. Bit shifting works regardless of endianness.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I appreciate your tutorial, and reiterate: The OP mentions 16 bits of unknown provenance... I answered with an easily alterable few lines of code to transform binary to ASCII hex digits... Thank you, but I do understand the problem, but have insufficient information to state which end is which... C'est la guerre...

Comment: @thebusybee Sadly, I remember when having 65K was still a dream for sometime in the future... Old habits die hard... `:-)`

Comment: Table indexed by a whole byte or even 2 bytes is good, but IMHO overkill - too many typing, unless you are willing to write a small program/script that will just generate it. So IMHO this answer with table of 16 hex digits is optimal.

Comment: @ivan.ukr You can also populate the table at runtime. The necessary loop is simple and small.

Comment: I still think such table is overkill and wasting of memory. 16-value table is optimal.

Comment: @ivan.ukr Having fun... Edit addition for the enthusiasts :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not specified all of your requirements and environment conditions, this list collects just ideas. Some might work, others not. It all depends on conditions you did not provide in your question. If some of the terms are new to you, use them as a starting point for research.

1. Use one or more tables to convert from binary to ASCII, as others suggested. This only speeds up the conversion.
2. Don't transmit ASCII, send binary values. An ASCII hex value as you probably use needs at least 5 characters, 4 for the number and 1 separator. The same value as binary has just 2 bytes. Additionally, you don't need any conversion.
3. Detach the acquirement of the data from the transmission. For example, you can use a circular buffer big enough to handle the average throughput. Be aware that you have multiple threads then, design your software carefully.

In any case, make sure the receiving machine can handle the data rate. PCs are notoriously known to depend on load and even "sleep" time after time, because their OS is not a real-time operating system.